# Issue with dividing the voltage and feeding it to an differential amplifier

Tags: differential, buffer

I have a ladder voltage divider which divides 70v into 7 different steps (10V each).

Output of this voltages is fed to a unity gain differential amplifier to get the difference voltage (70 - 60 = 10).

The problem is the resistor for differential amplifier are loading divided signals.

I want to use a high common mode voltage differential amplifier to accommodate 70v range

I tried looking for instrumentation amplifier but none are supporting common mode input range what I require

How to isolate the signal without using an high voltage buffer IC (these are costly)?

Comment: What's the end game? At the moment this sounds like an XY problem - you appear to be wanting 10 volts so why are you subtracting 60 volts from 70 volts when there are easier ways so, what are you trying to achieve here and why are you proposing to do it in a more complex way than what to me should be a simple way.

Comment: and if the "resistor for differential amplifier" (whatever that is) is loading your voltage divider: well, you found your design mistake, adjust these resistors.

Comment: Why do you require a 70V input common mode opamp, if you use a divider. It can be anything, just make sure you are using the non-inverting input of opamp (inst. amp) with very high input impedance, like J-FET input IA.

Comment: The main reason for doing this to to achieve precision measurement upto 70v. So if I down scale a 70 to 10v with dovision, my quantization error is huge. So I wanted to slice up 70v volts into 10V chunks and then measure each of  them with an 18 bit ADC. This would reduce my quantization error and increase accuracy. Suggest

Comment: Want to achieve an accuracy of <1mV

Comment: @siddharthtaunk um, that sounds ill-designed. if you want 1 mV at 70 V, that's 70000 quantization steps. That's just a little more then 16 bit. So, a single voltage divider feeding an 18 bit ADC would be more than sufficient. No need for your 7 different steps.

Comment: Mine scope differential probe measures up to +/-1.4kV and it uses an IA that has max input range of 1.5V. No divider steps. No high accuracy instrument does it in a way you think. Make something on already working principles, or buy a ready made device.

Comment: Sure Marko, thanks for all the inputs. So after the division I can use an IA to reduce the ground noise? And how will the resistance drifts be handled(we are using a precision resistor of 0.05 percent)?